# Is it possible to implement coroutines using only LISP primitives?

Tags: lisp, scheme, coroutine, continuation-passing

First, I'm a LISP newbie.

What I want to get is a cooperative micro-threading feature. And this can be gained with coroutine. As I know, Scheme supports coroutines via continuations.  However, not all Scheme implementation may have continuations.  If so, can I add a continuation feature with only LISP primitives?

Comment: About which kind of "LISP" are you talking?

Comment: @Svante Mainly Scheme, but possibly any kind of LISP. I talked about LISP 'primitives' which any LISP has. I wanna challenge to make own implementation if I could :)

Comment: Ah.  Well, I thought that you might mean some ancient dialect, one from the time where people still spelt it in all capitals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can. Chapters 5 and 6 of [Essentials of Programming Languages](http://www.eopl3.com/) shows how to implement continuations in Scheme. In his book [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html), Paul Graham explains how to implement continuations in Common Lisp (Chapters 20-22).

Comment: These 'continuations' for CL are relatively limited, I'd think.

Comment: @Rainer Can I know about the limitation?

Comment: @Eonil On Lisp contains an implementation of multi-threading on continuations, so co-routines also might be possible with that implementation.